# metrics for evaluating ranking algorithms

Tags: algorithm

I have created an algorithm that ranks entities .  I was wondering what should be my metrics to evaluate my algorithm. Are their any algorithm of these type to which I can compare mine?

Answer (score 1):

[Normalized discounted cumulative gain](http://www.kaggle.com/wiki/NormalizedDiscountedCumulativeGain) is one of the standard method of evaluating ranking algorithms. You will need to provide a score to each of the recommendations that you give. If your algorithm assigns a low (better) rank to a high scoring entity, your `NDCG` score will be higher, and vice versa.

The score can depend on the *aspect* in the query.

You can also manually create a gold data set, with each result assigned a score. You can then use these scores to calculate `NDCG`.

Note that what I call **score**, is referred to as **relevance** (*rel i*, relevance of ith result) in the formulas.